# Is it possible to play multiple audio tracks with delay and loop all?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Let's pretend I have 3 (or more) audio voice tracks. I want them to play like this:

Track1 > delay (x seconds) > Track2 > delay > Track3 > delay > Track1 etc...

This loop should continue for a defined amount of time. Simultanously, it should play background music. User also should be able to control voice volume and background music volume while playing.

Is this possible to do this and if yes, what is the best way to achieve it? For now I only checked the HTML audio element and it seems not to be capable to handle such custom scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is absolutely supported in the JavaScript Audio API. Use the  [AudioScheduledSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode).

> The AudioScheduledSourceNode interface—part of the Web Audio API—is a
> parent interface for several types of audio source node interfaces
> which share the ability to be started and stopped, optionally at
> specified times. Specifically, this interface defines the start() and
> stop() methods, as well as the onended event handler.

Which means you create an [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) for each of your *tracks* and then control the timing of them.

Alternatively, you could simply create multiple tracks as you describe and then play them intermittently/programmatically.

Here is a live example: [MDN Multi-Track Example](http://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/multi-track/)

And here is the [MDN provided](https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/tree/master/multi-track) source code for that example.

I think the issue you may run into with this second option is a delay between cueing up the tracks. It would be better to have each AudioBuffer combined into a single to avoid the switching delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a loop, and when it executes, create a new audio element, add a new audio file to it and append it to body and play.

But just to warn your, this is super hacky and I thought of the problem for half second :-)

The best thing would be to use a library for this.